# Why won’t my Raspberry PI 3 work?

Tags: gpio

I recently got a Raspberry Pi 3 and I’m trying to make a desktop computer with it. but when I got it setup by plugging in the hdmi cable the mouse and the keyboard putting the micro SD card and adding power, nothing happened on the screen.

Only the red LED comes on.

Comment: you have provided almost no information ...... what does this mean? `when I get it setup`

Comment: please post a full description of what you have done

Comment: There are two LEDs on the board, one red and one green.  What do they do when you plug the Pi in?

Comment: When I plug in the pi only a red LED comes on.

Comment: "putting the micro sd card" - what's **on** the micros SD card

Comment: The micro SD card has “NOOBS Operating System Installer” on it. I have the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ Starter Kit, so NOOBS was already installed on the micro SD card.

Comment: Only the red (PWR = power) LED coming on probably indicates the SD card is not properly formatted.  Try putting an image on it or another card yourself: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/README.md Although the Foundation recommends NOOBS, more people seem to have trouble with it that just plain Raspbian, which is most likely what you'd end up using anyway (NOOBS isn't a complete OS by itself, it just lets you choose one).  So from the "Downloads" link on that page, choose "Raspbian" which is right next to NOOBS at the top.

Comment: I have downloaded Noobs on a deferent SD card and checked the TV’s hdmi and  the hdmi cord and still have the same problem. I’m thinking it’s the Pi, what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Common issues with a new Pi are:

**- insufficient power**: the Pi3 needs a lot of power. Do not power it from USB, you need a DC power supply that supplies 2 Amps or more.

**- non-bootable SD card**: the SD card is everything. You need to have a proper OS installed (Raspbian is the preferred choice and Etcher is the preferred utility to write on the SD card).

Comment: `You need to have a proper OS installed` which has to be installed properly

Answer (score 1):

The data so far seems to suggest the following:

> 1. When I plug in the pi only a red LED comes on.
> 2. I have the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ Starter Kit

Your RPi seems to be powered correctly, and absent other information the most reasonable assumption is that it works.

> 3. The micro SD card has “NOOBS Operating System Installer” on it.

I'll assume that you have not actually seen the [NOOBS menu on your display, and used it to install](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/noobs.md) an OS iaw the [instructions](https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/blob/master/README.md). If this is the case, the following problem areas seem possible:

1. The SD card is defective, or you have inserted it incorrectly,
2. Your HDMI cable is defective,
3. You monitor/Television is not set correctly to display the HDMI channel you've plugged your cable into.

Please work through these possibilities, let us know if anything isn't clear, and update your question with any relevant results.